# Finding length of side on parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra

A parallelogram has sides $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, and $DA$. Given $A(1,-1,2)$, $C(2,1,0)$, and the midpoint $M(2,0,-3)$ of $AB$. Find $BD$.

I am unsure how to solve this question with the given midpoint and points. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: You can find $B$ using the fact that $M$ is the midpoint and the coordinates of the midpoint are the average of respective coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already have this, but the diagonals of any parallelogram (in this case $AC$ and $BD$) have as a midpoint the intersection of both diagonals. Having this information, first you can get the value of $B$ with the midpoint of $AB$:

$$M = (\frac{x_a+x_b}{2},\frac{y_a+y_b}{2},\frac{z_a+z_b}{2})$$ 
$$\implies B = (2*2-1,2*0+1,2*-3-2) = (3,1,-8)$$

Using the same formula for M, using the points $A$ and $C$ you can get the midpoint of the diagonal $AC$, which is also the midpoint of the diagonal $BD$. From there, you can get the value of $D$ and of the vector $BD$.